# Java2D using buttons and Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to create a tile editor sort of program where I have a viewport for rendering on the left side of the program, and then a panel of buttons on the right to use for opening files, saving the tiles etc... I was going to use LWJGL to do this, but it seems theres no good way to do it.

Essentially I guess I'm asking, how do I have a viewport for rendering using g.DrawImage or something, and then also have a panel of buttons next to that viewport?

Comment: you have to create a 'draw-panel', a panel which has a grid, and you can set the color of each grid field. if you set the color on the panel you also set the color (ans position) in the image you want to produce - this 'draw-panel' can be implementent in various form. once you have it you can add that panel with a scrollpanel so you can zoom (need implementation) and pan the image; 

in my opinion it's cheaper to use a freeware - but feel free to refine your questions^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jME3 as they support rendering in a canvas on a Swing window. There is even a tutorial on doing it in the tutorials section of the website.

You can also do it using a fully rendered window and then putting the buttons inside the scene. I'm surprised LWJGL doesn't support this though as jME3 is built on top of LWJGL.

Comment: LWJGL is just a graphics API, it doesn't know anything besides manipulating vertices and buffers. And I really don't want to use JME, I want to use Java2D.

Comment: You can write 2d games in jME (although you may be better off choosing a 2d graphics engine). For example see: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-neon-vector-shooter-in-jmonkeyengine-the-basics--gamedev-11616

Comment: No, I really don't want to use JME. I already have been learning OpenGL for two years, I don't need an engine for the games I make. I was just asking how to make a sort of tile editor in Java2D because I don't have much experience with it.